# When slide show web page is reopen, the web page loading is very slow

Tags: php, javascript

Here is a script that opens about 200 pictures, the first time you open the webpage, loading of the 200 pictures is fast. The slideshow display only one picture at a time as shown in the picture. [image: slideshow]

However if you reopen the page, it takes about 4 minutes to load the same page the second time. I was thinking if these data is stored in the cache memory, that would be a great idea if needs to be reopened.

```
    session_start();
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');


    if(!isset($_SESSION['token']) && (!isset($_SESSION['user']))){
        echo "<script language='javascript'>self.close();</script>";
    }
    require 'db.php';
    $upload_id = $_GET['id'];
    $client = $_GET['NAME'];
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Display | <?=$client;?></title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?
    $myid = $_GET['myd'];
    $mydept = $_GET['dept'];
    $myrole = $_GET['role'];
    ?>

    <?
    //}
    // Retrieving Book mark page for this job (upload_id)
    $book = ("SELECT * FROM bookmark WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND upload_id='".$upload_id."'  ");
    $bk = mysqli_query($conn, $book) or die ("ERROR bookmark ".mysqli_error($conn));
    $bookmark = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bk);
    $page  = $bookmark['page_book'];


    ?>
    <div class="w3-container">
     <center>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <?
    $s = ("SELECT count(USER_ID) as counter FROM upload_data WHERE UPLOAD_ID='".$upload_id."'");
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $s) or die ("ERROR ".mysqli_error($conn));
    $c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
    $all = $c['counter'];


    $sql = ("SELECT YEAR, FOLDER, USER_ID, FILE_NAME FROM upload_data WHERE UPLOAD_ID='".$upload_id."' ORDER BY USER_ID");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("ERROR ".mysqli_error($conn));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $file = $row['FILE_NAME'];
        //$all = $row['pages'];
        $year = $row['YEAR'];
        $folder = $row['FOLDER'];
        $id = $row['USER_ID'];
        $fileshow = "/$year/$folder/$file";
    ?>

    <div class="w3-display-container myPictures "  style="left: -15%; ">
        <img  src=<? echo $fileshow;?> style="width:130%; height: auto;" data-zoom-image=<? echo $fileshow;?>>
      <!--<div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        <?echo $id; ?>
      </div>-->
    </div>
    <?
    }
    ?>

     <button class="button5"  style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 20px; top: 140px; height: 40px; width: 100px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: Transparent;" onclick="bookSave(0)">Save</button>&nbsp;
     <div id="display"  style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 30px; top: 372px;" ></div>&nbsp;
     <button  class="button2" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 20px; top: 505px; height: 40px; width: 100px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: Transparent;;" onclick="plusDivs(-10)">&#10094;&#10094;10-</button>&nbsp;
     <font><div id="bookmark" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 20px; top: 190px; height: 60px; width: 100px;"></div></font></center>

    <div id="w20" class="clock"  style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 60%;"></div>

    <div class="message"  style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 50%;"></div>
    <button class="button" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 20px; top: 410px; height: 50px; width: 100px; border-radius: 2px;"  onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094; 前へ</button>
    <button class="button" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 20px; top: 300px; height: 50px; width: 100px; border-radius: 2px;"  onclick="plusDivs(1)">次へ &#10095;</button>
    <button  class="button2" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; left: 20px; top: 215px; height: 40px; width: 100px; border-radius: 2px; background-color: Transparent;" onclick="plusDivs(10)">+10&#10095;&#10095;</button>&nbsp;
    </div>
    <?$hour = $_GET['t'];?>
    <!---------------------------------------- Next | Prev Functions ------------------------------------------------------->
    <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myPictures");
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "timer5.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("index="+slideIndex+"&name=<?echo $client;?>&upload_id=<?echo $upload_id;?>&total=<?=$all;?>&myid=<?=$myid;?>&dept=<?=$mydept;?>&role=<?=$myrole;?>");
    <?if($_SESSION['id']==20000){?>
    function clock1(){
    var clock;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
                    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter'
                });
            });
    }
    var clock;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(<?=$hour;?>, {
                    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
                    countdown: true,
                    callbacks: {
                        stop: function() {
                            //$('.message').html('message here');
                            clock1();
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
    <?}?>
    }
    </script>


    <!-- ---------------------------------Save BookMark Functions ---------------------------------------->
    <script>
    function bookSave(n) {

    if(confirm('Save and Close?')){
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("bookmark").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "booksave.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("index="+slideIndex+"&name=<?echo $client;?>&upload_id=<?echo $upload_id;?>&myid=<?=$myid;?>");
     setTimeout("self.close()", 2000 ) // after 5 seconds
    }
     }
    </script>



    <!------------------------------------------------------ Call BookMark (PageNumber) when view ------------------------------------------------------------>
    <script>
    var slideIndex = <?=$page;?>;
    showBk(slideIndex);

    function bookMark(n) {
      showBk(slideIndex += n);
    }
    function showBk(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myPictures");
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "callbookmark.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("index="+slideIndex+"&name=<?echo $client;?>&upload_id=<?echo $upload_id; ?>");
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please read the two tags you chose for this post. Both point you to the fact that programming questions are off-topic here at superuser.

Comment: @n8te sorry if my tag is not proper for the question, what should be the tag? can you help me out, maybe it might get someone who understand the question...please

Comment: No, I'm not saying you chose the wrong tag. I'm saying your question is off-topic for superuser. Programming questions belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @n8te sorry for the inconvenient, actually I cannot post a question in Stack Overflow. That is why I ask here ...

Comment: I understand your predicament but your post is simply off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you, I had posted programming question here before and it was well addressed by the others...is it okay if I can keep it here for awhile?

Comment: You _might_ be able to ask it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it appears to be working code that just suffers from performance issues, but I am not certain since I am not a member of that site and I don't know exactly what kind of questions they allow. Read their [help-center/on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first to determine if your question is a good fit for that site.

Comment: Also, did you know there is a [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: thanks @n8te, I just posted my question in Code Review, I live in Japan but my Japanese is not that good...

Comment: Just curious - ***why*** cannot you post at S.O?  If you got banned, there are ways to get unbanned, which is what you ought to do, rather than spamming. What it you were banned here for spamming, would you ask your coding questions on our [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) sister site? Btw, you might want to consider why you have `header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');`

Comment: @Mawg thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it, I dont know where your questions are leading to? No help at all, btw, I think our time is wasted here !!!

Comment: My next comment is too long, so I posted it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best help that I an give is "first time fast, second time slow" sounds like it has to be a cache problem.

Especially as that is exactly the opposite of what should happen if you have good caching.

That `header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');` is turning off caching - why do you do that?

What I ***think*** is happening is that the first time you run, there is some caching in effect - until that line is hit. Which slows things for the rest of the first page load and for all of the second page load.

Please remove that line, try again and report back what happens (or ask on one of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/ or maybe even https://superuser.com/).

Comment: thank you Mawg I updated my question to draw a clear picture of my question. although I have added and removed that particular line, still no change.

Comment: oops, I just noticed `header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');` which will also mean that the page is never cached. Please remove both of those lines & let us know what happens.  Sorry that I missed that first time round.

Comment: I have removed the lines, still the same. The code was originally without a cache,  I tried with cache still no luck.

Comment: Than I am sorry, but I cannot help you. If you get no answer here, maybe ask on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try your suggestion. It seems like, with or without the cache header, the first time it loads its okay. However, if you close the page and reopen again, it takes about 4 to 5 mins to load the page and display the slideshow. About 200 pictures, however only 1 picture is displayed.

Comment: Sounds like  you have  to profile the code. At least that ought to narrow it down to a particular area, which might give you a clue. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks Mawg, I will try narrow it down... perhaps it might help

Comment: If you have some problematic code area, ask about it on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: thank you again....I will